# Get all id's expect in a specific column

Tags: mysql

I wanted to get all the category id's from category table expect the id's in a specific column.

i tried this `SELECT`category_id`FROM`category`WHERE`category_id`!=`priority_no` but its not working.

Table: [image: Table coluns]
Output: [image: Output]

And i want this output:
1
3
4
7

Comment: you mean category_id should not be equal to priority number ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query -

```
SELECT c1.category_id FROM category c1
  LEFT JOIN category c2 ON c1.category_id = c2.priority_no
WHERE c2.priority_no IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

This is Works For me

```
SELECT `category_id` FROM `category` WHERE `category_id` != IFNULL(`priority_no`,0)
```

Thanks.